# Dense layer. Network in python without TF

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some task to write layer without tensorflow. I have code, but it doesn't work and I can not understand why.

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Optional, Tuple

class Dense:

    def __init__(self, n_in: int, n_out: int, use_bias: bool = True):
        self.n_in = n_in
        self.n_out = n_out
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.w = np.random.normal(0.0, 1, (self.n_in, self.n_out))
        self.bies = np.random.random(size=(self.n_out))
        

    @property
    def weights(self) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, Optional[np.ndarray]]:
       """Returns weights used by the layer."""
        return self.w

    @property
    def input(self) -> np.ndarray:
        """Returns the last input received by the layer"""
        return self.n_in
        
    def __call__(self, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Performs the layer forward pass.

        Arguments:
            x: Input array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_in`)

        Returns:
            An array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_out`)"""
        if sefl.use_bias:
            res_i_w = sefl.x @ sefl.w + self.bies
        else:
            res_i_w = sefl.x @ sefl.w
        return np.reshape(res_i_w, (self.x.size, n_out))
        

    def grad(self, gradOutput: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, Tuple[np.ndarray, Optional[np.ndarray]]]:
        """Computes layer gradients

        Arguments:
            gradOutput: Gradient of loss function with respect to the layer output, an array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_out`).

        Returns:
            A tuple object:
                Gradient of loss function with respect to the layer input, an array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_in`)
                Gradient of loss function with respect to the layer's weights:
                    An array of shape (`n_in`, `n_out`).
                    Optional array of shape (`n_out`, )."""
        return (gradOutput @ self.w.T, (res_i_w.T @ gradOutput, gradOutput.sum(axis=0)))
```

text of task:

```
You need to implement a class in Python that describes a dense layer of a neural network.

Init:

The weights are initialized using uniformly distributed values in range [-1, 1]. 
Bias vector is not initialized if `use_bias` is False.
Weigths matrix has the shape (`n_in`, `n_out`), bias vector has the shape (`n_out`, ).
        Arguments:
            n_in: Positive integer, dimensionality of input space.
            n_out: Positive integer, dimensionality of output space.
            use_bias: Whether the layer uses a bias vector."
```

Comment: simply use `print()` inside class to see values in variable and which part of code is executed - it is called `'print debuging'`. You could also use some small example and compare it with calculations on paper.

Comment: without example `input` and expected `output` it is hard to run it and test it. If you use `random.seed(0)` in test then you can test it many times with the same random values.

Comment: what means `it doesn't work` ? Do you get wrong results? Show input data, output data and expected result. Do you get error? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it's true without example  it is hard, that's why I asked here, because I haven't example

Comment: I try to run it with any data and it gives error in `__call__`. First: you have typo in word `sefl` - it should be `self`. Second: you have to use `x` instead of `self.x`. Third: you have to use `self.n_out` instead of `n_out`.

Comment: first you should test it on local data - to see errors (which you have in few places)

Comment: we can't test it on this page because it needs login and password - but even if we could use it then it probably doesn't show errors - so it is useless when you develope code. First test code on local values - to see error and values in every step.

Comment: how would you write this code with these conditions, I will fix all the errors. but the example will make it much easier for me to understand?

Comment: I have no idea how I would write it - first I would need example data to test code at every step. Without example data it is useless. So first I would use Google to find some example. I would also check Wikipedia [Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), [Deep Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning), [Layer (dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_(deep_learning)). At this moment I test your code using useless example `Dense(5, 3, False)(np.array(range(5))`

Comment: other problem - if `n_in` is `5` then single example should be list with 5 elements - ie `example = list(range(5))` -and `batch` should be list of many examples - ie with 2 examples `batch = [example1, example2]` and then `batch_size` is number of examples - `x.shape[0]`, not number of all values in all examples `x.size`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it calculates values correctly but I at least found errors and fixed it.

I checked only `__call__`

1: you have typo in word `sefl` - it should be `self`.

2: you have to use `x` instead of `self.x`.

3: you have to use `self.n_out` instead of `n_out`

4: `batch` means array with many examples and `batch_size` should be number of these examples `x.shape[0]` but you use `x.size` which means number of all values in all examples.

5: it gives result with expected shape so it doesn't need `reshape

```
def __call__(self, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Performs the layer forward pass.

    Arguments:
        x: Input array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_in`)

    Returns:
        An array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_out`)"""

    #batch_size = x.shape[0]  # because (batch_size, n_in) = x.shape
    
    if self.use_bias:
        res_i_w = x @ self.w + self.bies
    else:
        res_i_w = x @ self.w
    
    #return np.reshape(res_i_w, (batch_size, self.n_out))
    return res_i_w
```

If you would set `self.bies = np.zeros((1, self.n_out))` when `use_bias` is `False` then you could reduce it to one line

```
    return x @ self.w + self.bies
```

Now I can test it with some data to see if it works - but I still can't say if it calculate it correctly:

```
n_in = 5
n_out = 3

example1 = list(range(0, n_in, 1))
example2 = list(range(n_in, 0, -1))

batch_input = np.array([example1, example2])
print(batch_input)

print('number of examples:', batch_input.shape[0])
print('n_in:', batch_input.shape[1])
 
layer = Dense(n_in, n_out, False) # ()

batch_output = layer(batch_input)
print(batch_output)
```

---

**Full code**

I use `np.random.seed(0)` to have always the same radom values in tests. This way I can run it many times with the same values. Normally you have to remove it.

```
import numpy as np
from typing import Optional, Tuple

class Dense:

    def __init__(self, n_in: int, n_out: int, use_bias: bool = True):
        self.n_in = n_in
        self.n_out = n_out
        self.use_bias = use_bias
        self.w = np.random.normal(0.0, 1, (self.n_in, self.n_out))
        self.bies = np.random.random(size=(self.n_out))

    @property
    def weights(self) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, Optional[np.ndarray]]:
        """Returns weights used by the layer."""
        return self.w

    @property
    def input(self) -> np.ndarray:
        """Returns the last input received by the layer"""
        return self.n_in
        
    def __call__(self, x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Performs the layer forward pass.

        Arguments:
            x: Input array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_in`)

        Returns:
            An array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_out`)"""
        
        #batch_size = x.shape[0]  # because (batch_size, n_in) = x.shape
        
        if self.use_bias:
            res_i_w = x @ self.w + self.bies
        else:
            res_i_w = x @ self.w
        
        #return np.reshape(res_i_w, (batch_size, self.n_out))
        return res_i_w
        

    def grad(self, gradOutput: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, Tuple[np.ndarray, Optional[np.ndarray]]]:
        """Computes layer gradients

        Arguments:
            gradOutput: Gradient of loss function with respect to the layer output, an array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_out`).

        Returns:
            A tuple object:
                Gradient of loss function with respect to the layer input, an array of shape (`batch_size`, `n_in`)
                Gradient of loss function with respect to the layer's weights:
                    An array of shape (`n_in`, `n_out`).
                    Optional array of shape (`n_out`, )."""
        return (gradOutput @ self.w.T, (res_i_w.T @ gradOutput, gradOutput.sum(axis=0)))

# --- test ---

n_in  = 5
n_out = 3

example1 = list(range(0, n_in, 1))
example2 = list(range(n_in, 0, -1))

batch_input = np.array([example1, example2])

print('--- batch_input ---')
print(batch_input)
print('number of examples :', batch_input.shape[0])
print('example size (n_in):', batch_input.shape[1])
 
layer = Dense(n_in, n_out, False)

batch_output = layer(batch_input)

print('--- batch_output ---')
print(batch_output)
print('number of examples  :', batch_output.shape[0])
print('example size (n_out):', batch_output.shape[1])
```

---

**BTW:** There is project [ML-From-Scratch](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/ML-From-Scratch) with all code in Python (with `numpy`).

Layer [Dense](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/ML-From-Scratch/blob/master/mlfromscratch/deep_learning/layers.py#L41) also runs it in one line `return X.dot(self.W) + self.w0` in `forward_pass()`